# Can 7-Keto DHEA permanently increase the resting metabolic rate in humans?

Tags: medical-science, medications, mehmet-oz

The latest fad weight loss pill is 7-Keto DHEA. It's been featured and recommended on the show "Dr. Oz", and [their website claims](http://www.doctoroz.com/videos/best-belly-blasting-supplements):

> 7-Keto works to counter this [dropping DHEA levels] by stimulating the thyroid to permanently raise your metabolism’s set point, or your resting metabolic rate, which is based on your body’s amount of fat and muscle.

Is there evidence supporting the claim that 7-Keto DHEA can permanently raise the metabolic rate in humans?

Comment: I have a non-answer. I checked Medline and couldn't find any studies relating to weight loss or increased metabolic rate due to 7-Keto DHEA. Some studies do show a correlation between high serum levels of DHEA and low adiposity, but taking oral 7-Keto DHEA doesn't affect serum hormone levels anyway, and that's a correlation.

Comment: I first heard about the Keto diet from Dr Steven Gundry on a podcast (Success Insider).  He mentions the 7-Keto DHEA.  He does reference some studies in the podcast but I haven't looked them up; some things sounded good, some things a bit wooly.  His new book is 'Unlocking the Keto Code', if someone would care read it & pick out the references and post them here that'd be ace.